# Xcode - TableView - Multiple sections

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have multiple sections in my TableView and I'm a bit stuck to display there names in the correct section. I'm new to xcode, so this an easy one for most but not for me :s

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if section == 0 {
    return areas.bars.count
    } else {

    return areas.clubs.count
}
}


 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("barsandclubsIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if  section == 0 { // **This is where I'm stuck I can't put section -> UITableViewCell**
    let bars = areas.bars
    let bar = bars[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = bar.name

    return cell
    } else {
        let clubs = areas.clubs
        let club = clubs[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = club.name

    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to return cell when section != 0?

Answer (score 1):

Try this may help you :

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("barsandclubsIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

if  indexPath.section == 0 { // **This is where I'm stuck I can't put section -> UITableViewCell**

    let bars = areas.bars
    let bar = bars[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = bar.name


}else {
    let clubs = areas.clubs
    let club = clubs[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = club.name
}

return cell
}
```

Comment: If answer finds helpful, then please mark it as accepted. So other users will find it helpful. Thanks